# Running Odoo behind nginx with docker

Tags: nginx, docker, odoo

I'm running multiple instances of odoo on the same machine using docker, every instance is ran on a different port and binded to 0.0.0.0
let's say:

```
odoo_1 is bound to 0.0.0.0:8069
odoo_2 is bound to 0.0.0.0:8070
```

I want to map each of these instances to a subdomain using nginx. I found this article but it seems like he's talking about containers that are not bound to hosts (sorry I'm new to docker)

http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/

To make my need clear, I need a way to generate an nginx config file for every odoo instance running with docker, given the mapping of port -> domain/subdomain.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running Odoo container with Nginx proxy - multi tenant setup, fast and dirty but works well:

https://github.com/swoldanski/odoo-nginx-docker-multitenant

Comment: thank for the answer, actually i'm trying to get it to work but odoo server doesn't recognize "--proxy-pass", any idea?

Comment: My bad, in github repo i have fixed (by you) version, with --proxy-mode not --proxy-pass. Thx Jacer